# Cocoa : Stack trace does not match line numbers ,?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have received a crash report from my cocoa app. The line number do not correspond with my app's source code. Any ideas why ? Even though this crash report comes from debug binaries ? 
I know which function it is crashing in, but I would like to identify the line number

The line below indicates number 5209 , my code does not even have this line. How can I relate this to my code ?

```
0x00000001000037b9 +[ITunesProvider getITunesMediaFiles:] + 5209
```

The full trace is

```
Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception \'NSRangeException\', reason: \'*** -[NSArray getObjects:range:]: index (1967) beyond bounds (0)\'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86c08784 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff832aaf03 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86bb3605 -[NSArray getObjects:range:] + 341
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86c128fe -[NSArray countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 206
    4   TestAppMac                        0x00000001000037b9 +[ITunesProvider getITunesMediaFiles:] + 5209
    5   TestAppMac                        0x000000010000913c -[AppController processFiles:] + 412
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8662a114 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
    7   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff84894fd6 _pthread_start + 331
    8   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff84894e89 thread_start + 13
)
```

Comment: the `+ x` is a byte offset into the code of the function. It seems to be only partially symbolicated, but you can tell that the problem is an array access in `getITunesMediaFiles`. Incidentally, that method is WAY too big. Use some helper methods.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, yea I can speculate the problem but, I thought if there was a way to get line numbers, I may well like to change build settings, if you can point out to me where to set that ?

Comment: If you can repro it in the debugger that would be best. Is this in a crash report file? Import it into Xcode and it will try to symbolicate it for you (line numbers).

Comment: Also -- methods should not be prefixed with `get`.

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to import it in the organizer of Xcode - this is a osx app's crash report.